# Why can't I comment on a post until I have 50 reputation?

Tags: discussion

If I get reputation by people upvoting my comments.... and I can't comment until I have 50 reputation...  How do I participate on this stack exchange?

Answer (score 5):

Hello and welcome to the site. Please have a read of the [Tour](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comments are a separate system from questions and answers. You don't get and reputation points from upvotes on comments, only from upvotes on questions and answers. And while it does take 50 rep points to comment, you don't need any to write a question or answer. So just get start asking or answering questions!

Comments have a reputation requirement because they are secondary. This site is not about discussion, so the system does not let new users write comments until they have used the site a little. That said, even brand new users can write comments on their own posts.